# Extra argument 'texture' in call

Tags: ios, swift

I've seen similar questions on here but I am new to Swift and programming this way, so I need a clear example please. I'm getting the error   **Extra argument 'texture' in call** with the following code:

```
// Setup settings button
let settingsTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "settings")
let settingsButton2 = Button(texture: settingsTexture, color: UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.0), size: settingsTexture.size())
settingsButton2.position = CGPointMake(view.frame.size.width - settingsTexture.size().width - 10, self.frame.size.height - 30)
settingsButton2.setPressedAction(pressedSettingsButton)
self.addChild(settingsButton2)
```

I'm getting error on the third line:

```
let settingsButton2 = Button(texture: settingsTexture, color: UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.0), size: settingsTexture.size())
```

Comment: What is type of `Button` here?

Comment: Is your Button class subclass of SKSpriteNode? Post init methods for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let settingsButton2 = Button(settingsTexture, color: UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.0), size: settingsTexture.size())
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your line with -

```
let settingsButton2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: settingsTexture, color: UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.0), size: settingsTexture.size())
```